# com.android.music.musicservicecommand doesn't stop spotify

Tags: android, spotify

Hey I'm using this code Snipped to stop the music play in Android:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
i.putExtra("command", "pause");
Context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

So everything is alright, while e.g google play music is running, but this snipped doesn't stop spotify playback.
Is it just for me or is it a general Problem and is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Spotify?

They very recently updated their app and it broke almost every known widget and API using item out there.

Have you looked at simply causing an artificial [KeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

Comment: I'm on the current version of spotify as I think.
Thanks I'll take a look on this.